# What is the difference between Zombie.js and Jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, zombie.js

May I know what is the difference between Zombie.js and Jasmine? are they both frameworks?

Answer (score 2):

**[Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/)** is a unit test framework for BDD (behavior driven development). It requires an execution environment like NodeJs or a browser like Firefox, Chrome, IE, PhantomJS etc. to run (and to provide the environment for the code under test). Jasmine provides the test execution and assertion infrastructure (that's the `describe()`, `it()`, `expect()`).

**[Zombie.js](http://zombie.js.org/)** is an emulated, headless browser. It's a browser on its own plus an interaction API for itself. It's like Selenium/Webdriver. It's using [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) under its hood to provide the APIs browsers usually provide. Zombie.js *requires* a test execution and assertion infrastructure (like [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) + [should.js](https://github.com/shouldjs/should.js) or even Jasmine).

---

- With Jasmine you write tests on a module or group-of-modules level. But usually not on an application level
- With Zombie.js you interact with a website (served by a server) through an interaction API.
- With Jasmine you make fine grained assertions on the output or events created for certain input - on the module level.
- With Zombie.js you interact with the whole application (or website).
- With Jasmine you test only the Javascript part.
- With Zombie.js you test the the frontent + backend. Though you might be able to mock away and intercept server interaction (maybe, I'm not familar with it).
- With Jasmine you call a method/function, pass a parameter and test the return value and events
- With Zombie.js you load a page and fill a form and test the output
- With Jasmine you need to run the tests in the proper execution envrionment (like Firefox, Chrome, ...)
- With Zombie.js you pages runs in a new execution environment
- With Jasmine you can test in browsers (consumers use) with their typical quirks
- With Zombie.js you test you application in a new browser with new quirks

---

Jasmine example:

```
    // spy on other module to know "method" was called on it
    spyOn(otherModule, "method");

    // create module
    let module = new Module(otherModule),
        returnValue;

    // calls otherModule.method() with the passed value too; always returns 42
    returnValue = module(31415);

    // assert result and interaction with other modules
    expect(returnValue).toBe(42);
    expect(otherModule.method).toHaveBeenCalledWith(31415);
```

Zombie.js example:

```
    // create browser
    const browser = new Browser();
    // load page by url
    browser.visit('/signup', function() {
        browser
            // enter form data by name/CSS selectors
            .fill('email', 'zombie@underworld.dead')
            .fill('password', 'eat-the-living')
            // interact, press a button
            .pressButton('Sign Me Up!', done);
    });

    // actual test for output data
    browser.assert.text('title', 'Welcome To Brains Depot');
```

---

Zombie.js, like Webdriver/Selenium, is no replacement for a unit testing framework like Jasmine, Mocha.

Comment: Thank You try-catch-finally!!